# Is it possible to get all the UIDs of the admins of a facebook page?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page and would like to get a list of all admins. I have tried using the **page** and **page_admin** *FQL tables*, but they require that I specify a UID.

I know we can check if a specific UID is a page admin or not but what we are trying is to know who the admins are without the user telling us.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly it seems that it is not possible to retrieve page fans or admins. It is possible to retrieve members of a group however.

You should request this feature on the developer bug tracker http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/